# How to set width and input limit of NumberInput widget for IntegerField in a Django form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-widget

I'm looking for a way to change the width of the input box in a Django form.

The model code for a parameter looks like this:

```
my_integer = models.IntegerField('Window', default=50)
```

And, putting it into a form, the HTML code that is generated is this:

```
<input id="id_my_integer" name="my_integer" value="50" type="number">
```

And, the box is quite wide - maybe 20 characters.

If I add the code in the definition of the form class Meta:

```
widgets = {
  'my_integer': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'3', 'maxlength':'3'}),
}
```

I get a box that is 5-6 characters wide that lets me insert 3 characters and the HTML code changes the type to type='text' and the increment/decrement arrows disappear.

So, **what I really want is a 3 character wide box, with a 3 character input limit, having the `NumberInput` widget's increment/decrement arrows. How do I do this?**

Comment: Use a [`NumberInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput) instead of a `TextInput`?

Answer (score 9):

The arrow controls are a part of the `NumberInput` widget, so you'll have to  use that. Unfortunately, in current HTML, there is no support for the `size` and `maxlength` attributes for the number input field `<input type="number">`.

The width of the field is easier to hack, you can simply override the CSS. You can use either `px` or `ch` as units, depending on what your requirement is. To have a 3 character wide input box, add `'style': 'width:3ch'` to the `attrs` dictionary. I'm using `6ch` in the example below because using exactly `3ch` leaves no space for the increment-decrement buttons.

To limit the number of characters entered, a simple `js` script will work. Here's the entire solution.

The widget:

```
widgets = {
    'my_integer': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
        'id': 'number_field',    
        'style': 'width:6ch',
        'oninput': 'limit_input()'
    }),
}
```

Inside your `template` file displaying the form, add this small script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function limit_input() {
        var field = document.getElementById("number_field");
        var max_length = 3;
        if (field.value.length > max_length) {
            field.value = field.value.slice(0, max_length); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Now in Django 2.1.7
you can use `size` in NumberInput attrs

```py
widgets = {
    'bank_account_number': form.NumberInput(attrs={'size': '20'}),
}
```

and just simply replace the attrs with `attrs={'style': 'width:6ch'}` works very well too. thanks Yash Tewari!

Comment: form needs an s, forms. I tried to edit but there was a backup and I was not allowed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to control the size of an input box and the number of characters, this is how I do it (I am citing a specific case involving an **integer** field here):

**In models.py:**

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

class SomeTable(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.IntegerField(default=1, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(9999),], )
```

**In forms.py:**

```
from .models import SomeTable

class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeTable
        fields = ('field1', 'field2')
        widgets = {
             'field2': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'style': 'width: 100px'}),
            }
```

As with a maximum value, (I have taken liberty to include it here) we may sometimes need to specify the **minimum** value as well, which has been shown in the sample codes above. And the width of the integer field can be controlled at the forms level using the widget "**NumberInput**". A reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput).

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me (Django 3.1.2) to limit the displayed size of an NumberInput field, thx

Answer (score 1):

You can set `style` for **field width**, `max` for **maximum number**, `min` for **minimum number** to [forms.NumberInput()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput) as shown below:

```py
widgets = {
    'my_integer': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
        'style': 'width:6ch', # For field width
        'max': '999',         # For maximum number
        'min': '0',           # For minimum number
    }),
}
```