# Django filters - adjusting box width

Tags: django, django-filter, django-widget-tweaks

With django_filters, I have my filterset, everything works fine it's just the display that I am stuck with (box width).

As you can see below, I have changed the "size" attribute of some of the filter options - because the default is too wide. But the "rating" one, which is a NumberInput, doesn't work for some reason. The "size" attribute works for TextInput but not NumberInput.

I want to change the size or rather the width of the NumberInput box that will be displayed in the template (see template pictures below).
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
class ReviewFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
comments = CharFilter(field_name='comments', lookup_expr='icontains', label="Comments ", widget=TextInput(attrs= {'size': 15 } ))
role_title = CharFilter(field_name='role_title', lookup_expr='icontains', label="Role title ", widget=TextInput(attrs={'size': 15 } ))
date_range = DateRangeFilter(field_name="date_created", label="   Posted date ")
**rating = CharFilter(field_name="rating", lookup_expr='gte', label="Minimum rating ", widget=NumberInput(attrs={'size': 1 } ))**
class Meta:
    model = Review1
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = {'recruiter', 'date_created', 'user'}
```

I have this:

[Screenshot - Look at "Minimum rating" box width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w6JL.png)

But I want this:

[Screenshot with filter search bar - Look at "Minimum rating" box width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jsfv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the thread below by using the attribute -  "style" : 'width6ch'

Apparently NumberInput doesn't have a working "size" attribute in HTML yet.

[Solution to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216135/how-to-set-width-and-input-limit-of-numberinput-widget-for-integerfield-in-a-dja)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly style the django-filters search fields. I was stuck with the same problem and here is my way of solving it.

Step 0 : intall `widget_tweaks` by `pip install django-widget-tweaks`

step 1 : add `widget_tweaks` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`

step 2 : add `{% load widget_tweaks %}` into your template.html

step 3 : style individual elements in template

```
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        {{ filter.form.comments.label_tag }}
        {% render_field filter.form.comments class="form-control" %}
    </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        {{ filter.form.role_title.label_tag }}
        {% render_field filter.form.role_title class="form-control" %}
    </div>
```

this way you can style individual form elements from filters, you can also add html tag attributes such as `type` or `class` and style them based on your needs.

you can use this link for reference. [Link for Reference](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html)